# How to prevent dispatch executing multiple times with hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

There is a simple code where i make the api call with react redux.
But there is one more thing. periodically i increase the progress value I show on the screen. I use useEffect for this. but when i increase progress, api goes back to call. I just want to make my api call once.

here is an example of my code

```
const Do = () => {

const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);

const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

dispatch(myApiCall);

useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress(progress => progress + 10);
   }, 1500);

   return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [progress]);

return ( 
       <ProgressBar
          completed={progress} 
      /> 
);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call the API in `useEffect` too:

```
const Do = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(myApiCall);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((progress) => progress + 10);
    }, 1500);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return <ProgressBar completed={progress} />;
};
```

Comment: thank you! it worked exactly the way I wanted it

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your api call inside of a componentDidMount equivalent `useEffect`:

```
const Do = () => {

    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);

    const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(myApiCall);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
       const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setProgress(progress => progress + 10);
          }, 1500);

       return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [progress]);

    return ( 
      <ProgressBar
        completed={progress} 
    /> 
   );
};
```

Comment: this answer works exactly the way I want it too. thank you!